# How to filter list using custom equality

Tags: java

I have a list of objects. The Object looks similar to this one:

```
class Data {

    ...

    private X somethig;
    private Y somethigElse;

    public boolean customEquals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Data)) {
            return false;
        }
        Data other = (Data) obj;
        if (something == null) {
            if (other.something != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!something.equals(other.something)) {
            return false;
            }
        if (somethigElse == null) {
            if (other.somethigElse != null) {
            return false;
            }
        } else if (!somethigElse.equals(other.somethigElse)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;       
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        ...
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        ...
    }

    getters/setters

}
```

I need to filter the list to get distinct objects from it.

Note the equals and hashCode methods are implemented (they use another fields) and I can't use equals for this task. So the equality is not defined by equals but by 'something' and 'somethigElse' properties. How can I do that?

I have tried:

```
final Comparator<Data> comparator = new Comparator<Data>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
            return o1.customEquals(o2) ? 0 : 1;
    }
};
Set<Data> set = new TreeSet<Data>(comparator);
set.addAll(list);
System.out.println(set);
```

But the set still contains some of the objects several times.

Comment: That fact you made *somethig* and *somethigelse* private member variables is making me cringe - but I get the point :D

Comment: Your compare method is broken. For two objects that aren't equal, both compare(a,b) and compare(b,a) returns a positive value. This renders the behavior of your TreeSet undefined.

Comment: Can you over-ride equals() to use something and somethingElse? Also, if you want only distinct objects, why not use a Set?

Comment: You are never returning -1 !

Comment: The solution using Comparator was my first attempt to solve it. But it apparently doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are not providing a proper ordering function.

`TreeSet` sorting algorithm makes a few assumptions, like:

```
compare(a, b) > 0 => compare(b, a) < 0
compare(a, b) > 0 && compare(b, c) > 0 => compare(a, c) > 0
```

and so on.

Implement a proper comparison, not just an 'equals' and it should work.

```
final Comparator<Data> comparator = new Comparator<Data>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        int k = o1.getSomething().compareTo(o2.getSomething();
        if (k != 0) {
            return k;
        }
        return o1.getSomethingElse() - o2.getSomethingElse();
    }
};
```

That is because `TreeSet` is a `SortedSet`, and you are telling that every new element that arrives is greater than others but itself.

Let's make a simplification to have a shorter example of what's going on, suppose that we are using just numbers with your comparator and the storage is an array (and binary search) rather than a tree because it's easier to represent.

We got number `1`, it's the only element, so the array is `[1]` now.

We get a `0` now, but as you are telling the set that it's bigger, we get `[1, 0]`.

Let's add a 3 now for example, we'll get `[1, 0, 3]`.

Add another `1`, the bisection will try to compare it with the middle element `0` and see that it's greater, go to the other half, compare with the `3` and it's greater again, so we get `[1, 0, 3, 1]`.

If we add another `1`, now it will see that the element is already there and won't add it, but if you add any other number and it happens that its repetitions are not in any of the bisection points, it will always end up at the end of the array.

Comment: Please, see the edited answer. The problem is, I don't care about comparsion of the properties. I just care about equality.

Comment: OK, you don't, but `TreeSet` does

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to fix your `compare()`:

```
public int compare(Data o1, Data o2)
{
  int i = o1.getSomething().compareTo(o2.getSomething());
  if (i != 0) return i;
  return o1.getSomethingElse()- o2.getSomethingElse();
}
```